# Get modem msisdn from incoming smstools

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, usb, ethernet-port, gsm

I have device and modem connected with sim card. And I have raspberry and smstools installed in the device. It all works very good with smsd configuration. When sms is sent to the the number of the sim card inset in the modem, we can see a file added in incoming folder like this

```
    From: 123456789
    From_TOA: 91 international, ISDN/telephone
    From_SMSC: 6543212
    Sent: 17-04-14 17:25:58
    Received: 17-04-14 17:30:38
    Subject: GSM1
    Modem: GSM1
    IMSI: 89898989898986767676
    Report: no
    Alphabet: ISO
    Length: 7
    PDU: 1234567890POIUYTREWQ1234567890POIUYTREWQ


    this is CONTENT
```

Almost all the things there give the information needed, except one thing it doesn't provide the phone number the message is sent to (which is the phone number of the sim card in the modem itself) Is there anybody can help me to achieve this, Please?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to have nothing to do with the Pi, and there are 2 numbers (if apparently dummy).

Comment: The configuration of smsd is in `/home/pi` which can be related to this. The two number `From` is the from number. The `From_SMSC` is the `smsc` of the from number.

Comment: Still not Pi related. Mobiles **DO NOT** use MSISDN for communication; all signalling is to IMSI